# Cassandra on docker getting stuck after creating default superuser role 'cassandra'

Tags: docker, cassandra

I am trying to build docker image of my Spring Boot Application which uses Cassandra. So I am trying to install and run it on my container, but after executing

```
    RUN cassandra -fR
```

from my Dockerfile (to make Cassandra listen on 127.0.0.1:9042) it's getting stuck after following statement:

```
    INFO  [OptionalTasks:1] 2019-06-10 21:05:51,677 CassandraRoleManager.java:356 - Created default superuser role 'cassandra'
```

I have been waiting for more than 20 minutes, but it's completely not willing to move on. I also tried to execute just **cassandra -f**, but bash returns with following statement:

```
    Running Cassandra as root user or group is not recommended - please start Cassandra using a different system user. If you really want to force running Cassandra as root, use -R command line option. The command '/bin/sh -c cassandra -f' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

So looks like it needs **-R** flag to run. I also tried **cassandra -R** command, but i doesn't make Casssandra listen on 127.0.0.1:9042. Any ideas how can i fix this? Maybe installing another version of Cassandra?

**Dockerfile:**

```
    FROM ubuntu:18.04
    RUN apt-get -y update
    RUN apt-get install -y sudo
    RUN sudo apt-get -y install curl
    RUN apt-get -y update && apt-get install -y gnupg2
    RUN echo "deb http://www.apache.org/dist/cassandra/debian 311x main" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/cassandra.sources.list
    RUN curl https://www.apache.org/dist/cassandra/KEYS | sudo apt-key add -
    RUN apt-get -y update
    RUN apt-get install -y software-properties-common apt-utils locales tzdata
    RUN echo "tzdata tzdata/Areas select Europe" > timezone.txt
    RUN debconf-set-selections timezone.txt
    RUN apt-get -y install cassandra
    RUN sudo service cassandra start
    RUN sudo update-rc.d cassandra defaults
    RUN cassandra -fR

    FROM openjdk:8
    ADD target/api.jar api.jar
    EXPOSE 8080
    ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "api.jar"]
```

Result of executing **cassandra -fR**, after the last line it gets stuck (not entire, it's to long) :

```
    INFO  [main] 2019-06-10 21:05:37,475 MigrationManager.java:337 - Create new Keyspace: KeyspaceMetadata{name=system_traces, params=KeyspaceParams{durable_writes=true, replication=ReplicationParams{class=org.apache.cassandra.locator.SimpleStrategy, replication_factor=2}}, tables=[org.apache.cassandra.config.CFMetaData@2b586f8b[cfId=c5e99f16-8677-3914-b17e-960613512345,ksName=system_traces,cfName=sessions,flags=[COMPOUND],params=TableParams{comment=tracing sessions, read_repair_chance=0.0, dclocal_read_repair_chance=0.0, bloom_filter_fp_chance=0.01, crc_check_chance=1.0, gc_grace_seconds=0, default_time_to_live=0, memtable_flush_period_in_ms=3600000, min_index_interval=128, max_index_interval=2048, speculative_retry=99PERCENTILE, caching={'keys' : 'ALL', 'rows_per_partition' : 'NONE'}, compaction=CompactionParams{class=org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompactionStrategy, options={min_threshold=4, max_threshold=32}}, compression=org.apache.cassandra.schema.CompressionParams@b9dae77a, extensions={}, cdc=false},comparator=comparator(),partitionColumns=[[] | [client command coordinator duration request started_at parameters]],partitionKeyColumns=[session_id],clusteringColumns=[],keyValidator=org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UUIDType,columnMetadata=[client, command, session_id, coordinator, request, started_at, duration, parameters],droppedColumns={},triggers=[],indexes=[]], org.apache.cassandra.config.CFMetaData@24f5ebb6[cfId=8826e8e9-e16a-3728-8753-3bc1fc713c25,ksName=system_traces,cfName=events,flags=[COMPOUND],params=TableParams{comment=tracing events, read_repair_chance=0.0, dclocal_read_repair_chance=0.0, bloom_filter_fp_chance=0.01, crc_check_chance=1.0, gc_grace_seconds=0, default_time_to_live=0, memtable_flush_period_in_ms=3600000, min_index_interval=128, max_index_interval=2048, speculative_retry=99PERCENTILE, caching={'keys' : 'ALL', 'rows_per_partition' : 'NONE'}, compaction=CompactionParams{class=org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompactionStrategy, options={min_threshold=4, max_threshold=32}}, compression=org.apache.cassandra.schema.CompressionParams@b9dae77a, extensions={}, cdc=false},comparator=comparator(org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.TimeUUIDType),partitionColumns=[[] | [activity source source_elapsed thread]],partitionKeyColumns=[session_id],clusteringColumns=[event_id],keyValidator=org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UUIDType,columnMetadata=[activity, event_id, session_id, source, thread, source_elapsed],droppedColumns={},triggers=[],indexes=[]]], views=[], functions=[], types=[]}
    INFO  [MigrationStage:1] 2019-06-10 21:05:39,744 ViewManager.java:137 - Not submitting build tasks for views in keyspace system_traces as storage service is not initialized
    INFO  [MigrationStage:1] 2019-06-10 21:05:39,748 ColumnFamilyStore.java:430 - Initializing system_traces.events
    INFO  [MigrationStage:1] 2019-06-10 21:05:39,753 ColumnFamilyStore.java:430 - Initializing system_traces.sessions
    INFO  [main] 2019-06-10 21:05:39,772 MigrationManager.java:337 - Create new Keyspace: KeyspaceMetadata{name=system_distributed, params=KeyspaceParams{durable_writes=true, replication=ReplicationParams{class=org.apache.cassandra.locator.SimpleStrategy, replication_factor=3}}, tables=[org.apache.cassandra.config.CFMetaData@4351824b[cfId=759fffad-624b-3181-80ee-fa9a52d1f627,ksName=system_distributed,cfName=repair_history,flags=[COMPOUND],params=TableParams{comment=Repair history, read_repair_chance=0.0, dclocal_read_repair_chance=0.0, bloom_filter_fp_chance=0.01, crc_check_chance=1.0, gc_grace_seconds=864000, default_time_to_live=0, memtable_flush_period_in_ms=3600000, min_index_interval=128, max_index_interval=2048, speculative_retry=99PERCENTILE, caching={'keys' : 'ALL', 'rows_per_partition' : 'NONE'}, compaction=CompactionParams{class=org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompactionStrategy, options={min_threshold=4, max_threshold=32}}, compression=org.apache.cassandra.schema.CompressionParams@b9dae77a, extensions={}, cdc=false},comparator=comparator(org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.TimeUUIDType),partitionColumns=[[] | [coordinator exception_message exception_stacktrace finished_at parent_id range_begin range_end started_at status participants]],partitionKeyColumns=[keyspace_name, columnfamily_name],clusteringColumns=[id],keyValidator=org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.CompositeType(org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UTF8Type,org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UTF8Type),columnMetadata=[status, id, coordinator, finished_at, participants, exception_stacktrace, parent_id, range_end, range_begin, exception_message, keyspace_name, started_at, columnfamily_name],droppedColumns={},triggers=[],indexes=[]], org.apache.cassandra.config.CFMetaData@7e5c619e[cfId=deabd734-b99d-3b9c-92e5-fd92eb5abf14,ksName=system_distributed,cfName=parent_repair_history,flags=[COMPOUND],params=TableParams{comment=Repair history, read_repair_chance=0.0, dclocal_read_repair_chance=0.0, bloom_filter_fp_chance=0.01, crc_check_chance=1.0, gc_grace_seconds=864000, default_time_to_live=0, memtable_flush_period_in_ms=3600000, min_index_interval=128, max_index_interval=2048, speculative_retry=99PERCENTILE, caching={'keys' : 'ALL', 'rows_per_partition' : 'NONE'}, compaction=CompactionParams{class=org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompactionStrategy, options={min_threshold=4, max_threshold=32}}, compression=org.apache.cassandra.schema.CompressionParams@b9dae77a, extensions={}, cdc=false},comparator=comparator(),partitionColumns=[[] | [exception_message exception_stacktrace finished_at keyspace_name started_at columnfamily_names options requested_ranges successful_ranges]],partitionKeyColumns=[parent_id],clusteringColumns=[],keyValidator=org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.TimeUUIDType,columnMetadata=[requested_ranges, exception_message, keyspace_name, successful_ranges, started_at, finished_at, options, exception_stacktrace, parent_id, columnfamily_names],droppedColumns={},triggers=[],indexes=[]], org.apache.cassandra.config.CFMetaData@44673092[cfId=5582b59f-8e4e-35e1-b913-3acada51eb04,ksName=system_distributed,cfName=view_build_status,flags=[COMPOUND],params=TableParams{comment=Materialized View build status, read_repair_chance=0.0, dclocal_read_repair_chance=0.0, bloom_filter_fp_chance=0.01, crc_check_chance=1.0, gc_grace_seconds=864000, default_time_to_live=0, memtable_flush_period_in_ms=3600000, min_index_interval=128, max_index_interval=2048, speculative_retry=99PERCENTILE, caching={'keys' : 'ALL', 'rows_per_partition' : 'NONE'}, compaction=CompactionParams{class=org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompactionStrategy, options={min_threshold=4, max_threshold=32}}, compression=org.apache.cassandra.schema.CompressionParams@b9dae77a, extensions={}, cdc=false},comparator=comparator(org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UUIDType),partitionColumns=[[] | [status]],partitionKeyColumns=[keyspace_name, view_name],clusteringColumns=[host_id],keyValidator=org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.CompositeType(org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UTF8Type,org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UTF8Type),columnMetadata=[view_name, status, keyspace_name, host_id],droppedColumns={},triggers=[],indexes=[]]], views=[], functions=[], types=[]}
    INFO  [MigrationStage:1] 2019-06-10 21:05:40,419 ViewManager.java:137 - Not submitting build tasks for views in keyspace system_distributed as storage service is not initialized
    INFO  [MigrationStage:1] 2019-06-10 21:05:40,422 ColumnFamilyStore.java:430 - Initializing system_distributed.parent_repair_history
    INFO  [MigrationStage:1] 2019-06-10 21:05:40,426 ColumnFamilyStore.java:430 - Initializing system_distributed.repair_history
    INFO  [MigrationStage:1] 2019-06-10 21:05:40,430 ColumnFamilyStore.java:430 - Initializing system_distributed.view_build_status
    INFO  [main] 2019-06-10 21:05:40,441 StorageService.java:1483 - JOINING: Finish joining ring
    INFO  [main] 2019-06-10 21:05:40,766 MigrationManager.java:337 - Create new Keyspace: KeyspaceMetadata{name=system_auth, params=KeyspaceParams{durable_writes=true, replication=ReplicationParams{class=org.apache.cassandra.locator.SimpleStrategy, replication_factor=1}}, tables=[org.apache.cassandra.config.CFMetaData@20239816[cfId=5bc52802-de25-35ed-aeab-188eecebb090,ksName=system_auth,cfName=roles,flags=[COMPOUND],params=TableParams{comment=role definitions, read_repair_chance=0.0, dclocal_read_repair_chance=0.0, bloom_filter_fp_chance=0.01, crc_check_chance=1.0, gc_grace_seconds=7776000, default_time_to_live=0, memtable_flush_period_in_ms=3600000, min_index_interval=128, max_index_interval=2048, speculative_retry=99PERCENTILE, caching={'keys' : 'ALL', 'rows_per_partition' : 'NONE'}, compaction=CompactionParams{class=org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompactionStrategy, options={min_threshold=4, max_threshold=32}}, compression=org.apache.cassandra.schema.CompressionParams@b9dae77a, extensions={}, cdc=false},comparator=comparator(),partitionColumns=[[] | [can_login is_superuser salted_hash member_of]],partitionKeyColumns=[role],clusteringColumns=[],keyValidator=org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UTF8Type,columnMetadata=[salted_hash, member_of, role, can_login, is_superuser],droppedColumns={},triggers=[],indexes=[]], org.apache.cassandra.config.CFMetaData@28236d5[cfId=0ecdaa87-f8fb-3e60-88d1-74fb36fe5c0d,ksName=system_auth,cfName=role_members,flags=[COMPOUND],params=TableParams{comment=role memberships lookup table, read_repair_chance=0.0, dclocal_read_repair_chance=0.0, bloom_filter_fp_chance=0.01, crc_check_chance=1.0, gc_grace_seconds=7776000, default_time_to_live=0, memtable_flush_period_in_ms=3600000, min_index_interval=128, max_index_interval=2048, speculative_retry=99PERCENTILE, caching={'keys' : 'ALL', 'rows_per_partition' : 'NONE'}, compaction=CompactionParams{class=org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompactionStrategy, options={min_threshold=4, max_threshold=32}}, compression=org.apache.cassandra.schema.CompressionParams@b9dae77a, extensions={}, cdc=false},comparator=comparator(org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UTF8Type),partitionColumns=[[] | []],partitionKeyColumns=[role],clusteringColumns=[member],keyValidator=org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UTF8Type,columnMetadata=[role, member],droppedColumns={},triggers=[],indexes=[]], org.apache.cassandra.config.CFMetaData@c3d8f[cfId=3afbe79f-2194-31a7-add7-f5ab90d8ec9c,ksName=system_auth,cfName=role_permissions,flags=[COMPOUND],params=TableParams{comment=permissions granted to db roles, read_repair_chance=0.0, dclocal_read_repair_chance=0.0, bloom_filter_fp_chance=0.01, crc_check_chance=1.0, gc_grace_seconds=7776000, default_time_to_live=0, memtable_flush_period_in_ms=3600000, min_index_interval=128, max_index_interval=2048, speculative_retry=99PERCENTILE, caching={'keys' : 'ALL', 'rows_per_partition' : 'NONE'}, compaction=CompactionParams{class=org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompactionStrategy, options={min_threshold=4, max_threshold=32}}, compression=org.apache.cassandra.schema.CompressionParams@b9dae77a, extensions={}, cdc=false},comparator=comparator(org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UTF8Type),partitionColumns=[[] | [permissions]],partitionKeyColumns=[role],clusteringColumns=[resource],keyValidator=org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UTF8Type,columnMetadata=[role, resource, permissions],droppedColumns={},triggers=[],indexes=[]], org.apache.cassandra.config.CFMetaData@2d4639b4[cfId=5f2fbdad-91f1-3946-bd25-d5da3a5c35ec,ksName=system_auth,cfName=resource_role_permissons_index,flags=[COMPOUND],params=TableParams{comment=index of db roles with permissions granted on a resource, read_repair_chance=0.0, dclocal_read_repair_chance=0.0, bloom_filter_fp_chance=0.01, crc_check_chance=1.0, gc_grace_seconds=7776000, default_time_to_live=0, memtable_flush_period_in_ms=3600000, min_index_interval=128, max_index_interval=2048, speculative_retry=99PERCENTILE, caching={'keys' : 'ALL', 'rows_per_partition' : 'NONE'}, compaction=CompactionParams{class=org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompactionStrategy, options={min_threshold=4, max_threshold=32}}, compression=org.apache.cassandra.schema.CompressionParams@b9dae77a, extensions={}, cdc=false},comparator=comparator(org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UTF8Type),partitionColumns=[[] | []],partitionKeyColumns=[resource],clusteringColumns=[role],keyValidator=org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UTF8Type,columnMetadata=[resource, role],droppedColumns={},triggers=[],indexes=[]]], views=[], functions=[], types=[]}
    INFO  [MigrationStage:1] 2019-06-10 21:05:41,515 ViewManager.java:137 - Not submitting build tasks for views in keyspace system_auth as storage service is not initialized
    INFO  [MigrationStage:1] 2019-06-10 21:05:41,517 ColumnFamilyStore.java:430 - Initializing system_auth.resource_role_permissons_index
    INFO  [MigrationStage:1] 2019-06-10 21:05:41,522 ColumnFamilyStore.java:430 - Initializing system_auth.role_members
    INFO  [MigrationStage:1] 2019-06-10 21:05:41,527 ColumnFamilyStore.java:430 - Initializing system_auth.role_permissions
    INFO  [MigrationStage:1] 2019-06-10 21:05:41,532 ColumnFamilyStore.java:430 - Initializing system_auth.roles
    INFO  [main] 2019-06-10 21:05:41,731 NativeTransportService.java:70 - Netty using native Epoll event loop
    INFO  [main] 2019-06-10 21:05:41,769 Server.java:155 - Using Netty Version: [netty-buffer=netty-buffer-4.0.44.Final.452812a, netty-codec=netty-codec-4.0.44.Final.452812a, netty-codec-haproxy=netty-codec-haproxy-4.0.44.Final.452812a, netty-codec-http=netty-codec-http-4.0.44.Final.452812a, netty-codec-socks=netty-codec-socks-4.0.44.Final.452812a, netty-common=netty-common-4.0.44.Final.452812a, netty-handler=netty-handler-4.0.44.Final.452812a, netty-tcnative=netty-tcnative-1.1.33.Fork26.142ecbb, netty-transport=netty-transport-4.0.44.Final.452812a, netty-transport-native-epoll=netty-transport-native-epoll-4.0.44.Final.452812a, netty-transport-rxtx=netty-transport-rxtx-4.0.44.Final.452812a, netty-transport-sctp=netty-transport-sctp-4.0.44.Final.452812a, netty-transport-udt=netty-transport-udt-4.0.44.Final.452812a]
    INFO  [main] 2019-06-10 21:05:41,769 Server.java:156 - Starting listening for CQL clients on localhost/127.0.0.1:9042 (unencrypted)...
    INFO  [main] 2019-06-10 21:05:41,803 CassandraDaemon.java:556 - Not starting RPC server as requested. Use JMX (StorageService->startRPCServer()) or nodetool (enablethrift) to start it
    INFO  [OptionalTasks:1] 2019-06-10 21:05:51,677 CassandraRoleManager.java:356 - Created default superuser role 'cassandra'
```

Comment: I would suggest to separate a Cassandra container (and use official image: https://hub.docker.com/_/cassandra/) and your application container...

Comment: Do you mean running cassandra image and then running my application image? Or running multi-container application with docker-compose? I'm trying first option, so I run cassandra image and then run image of my app, but it doesn't see cassandra on 127.0.0.1:9042. Forgive me for my ignorance (I'm making my first steps with Docker ), it's a part of my task (build Dockerfile of my app, and when it will be started, it should run the app), but I really don't have idea how to do it. I tried almost everything, including youtube tutorials and reading documentation, but nothing worked.

Comment: yes - you need to use 2 separate images, but you need to specify IP of the Cassandra container, not the `127.0.0.1` - every docker container has it's own localhost address, that is local to it

Comment: I tried this out - these are command I have executed: **`docker run --name cassandra-db --network bridge -d -p 9042:80 cassandra:latest`** , then **`docker run --name rest-api-app --link cassandra-db:rest-api -p 8080:80 -d cassandra
`** and finally **`docker start <built-container-id>`**, but my app still can't find cassandra.. It throws **`com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException: All host(s) tried for query failed (tried: localhost/127.0.0.1:9042 (com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.TransportException: [localhost/127.0.0.1:9042] Cannot connect))
`**

Comment: what are you specifying as contact point in your app? `127.0.0.1`?

Comment: Yes, localhost.

Comment: Local host is specific to container... you need to use name of host that you used in the link - please refer to help for docker run for more details

Comment: In fact, I have to build a docker image of my app, which will be starting my application if ran and push it to DockerHub. So I don't even know if I have to push only image of the app, without Cassandra (which it requires to work properly), or include it in some way to my image?

Comment: just push your image only... I would really recommend to read something like "Using Docker" book to get better understanding of concepts, etc.